# Django : order by 2 dates

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model containing date fields, and I want to sort the instance by 3 date fields. Now, I tried this :

```
class Task(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False) 
    date_start = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today) 
    date_end = models.DateField() 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_start','-date_end','-created_at']
```

So if I have these 3 instances :

- Task1 (date_start=22/05/2016, date_end=26/05/2016, created_at=22/05/2016)
- Task2 (date_start=30/10/2016, date_end=01/01/2017, created_at=22/05/2016)
- Task3 (date_start=30/10/2016, date_end=25/12/2016, created_at=22/05/2016)

I want to have this order :

1. Task1   (date_start is the first)
2. Task3   (date_start like Task3 but date_end is more recent)
3. Task2

Why my ordering doesn't works ?

Comment: shouldn't it  be more like `['date_start',' date_end']`? `-` in from indicates descending order

Comment: Yes, it's works, thank you !

Comment: i'll move it to answer. please vote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this: `['date_start',' date_end']`

`-` sign indicates descending order, but you want ascending order.

More docs: [order_by docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)